# Detailsview in ASP.Net cancel default editMode on client side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, detailsview

I have a main grid and detailsview with SQL DataSource binding, which is by default set to EditMode during load. And i am allowing the user to select a row in my main grid to load the details view in a modal popup (the data key is supplied for details view for loading selected row data), and updating the detailsview data to database on successfull entry and update by user.
When user enters unexpected data in detailsview, i am trying to show the respective validations to user using client side javascript alert messages, and allowing the user to close the Modal popup, using the modal popup cancelCommand option.
Note: here i am not cancelling the edit mode (Dont know how to do this on client side)

The problem i am facing is, after wrong data entry in details view the user may choose to close the detailsview and reopen the same data (by selecting the same row previously selected in main grid). Now the previous wrong data is loaded in the details (entered by user) and not the actual/ correct data from database/ SQL DataSource.

I tried setting the DetailsView ViewState to 'false', and eventhough the detailsview is trying to load data, the previous wrong values are populated. Can someone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I have solved the above issue by calling databind operation for DetailsView, on main Gridview **onRowSelect** command  *Note: For the detailsview, the viewstate is set to false, so that we bind the data to DetailsView always. In my scenario, i am not invloved in any additional call to database since my SQLDataSource viewstate is set to true*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the above issue by calling databind operation for DetailsView, on main Gridview- **onRowSelect** command
*Note: For the detailsview, the viewstate is set to 'false', so that we bind the data to DetailsView always. In my scenario, i am not invloved in any additional call to database since my SQLDataSource (bound to DetailsView) **viewstate is set to true***

```cs
protected void MainGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.CommandName == "select")
    {
        //Binds DetailsView with source data, not loading wrong data from edit mode if user selects previously selected same row again
        DetailsView.DataBind();
        this.mdlPopup.Show();
    }
}
```